# DateField -- "enter a valid date" message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm a bit confused as why it keeps returning the 'enter a valid date' message. Is it my formatting?

I've tried different combinations of %m-%d-%Y, but still no luck.

models.py

```
class DeliveryDate(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cart.id)
        return self.date
```

views.py

```
def add_delivery_date(request):

    the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    form = DeliveryDateForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            delivery_date = form.save(commit=False)
            date = request.POST['date']

            delivery_date = DeliveryDate.objects.create(cart=cart, date=date)
            delivery_date.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('thank-you.html')

    context = {
        "form": form
    }


    return render(request, 'choose_delivery_date.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class DeliveryDateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m %d %Y'], widget=SelectDateWidget, initial=datetime.date.today())

    class Meta:
        model = DeliveryDate
        fields = ['date']
```

Comment: What are you entering in the field?

Comment: Any date after today's date.

Comment: *Exactly* what are you entering in the field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First in your Django ModelForm let's change the date model field's widget without adding an extra field.
This is done in the __ init __ method :

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget

class DeliveryDateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeliveryDateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #Change date field's widget here
        self.fields['date'].widget = SelectDateWidget()

    class Meta:
        model = DeliveryDate
        fields = ['date']
```

By adding a field like you did :

```
class DeliveryDateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m %d %Y'], widget=SelectDateWidget, initial=datetime.date.today())
```

Is actually adding an extra FormField to your ModelForm which has the same name than the ModelField.
Doing this way, you'll simply change the binded date ModelField widget to 3 selects for Day/month/year

Second, your form validation is quit odd :
What I usually write looks like that:

```
def add_delivery_date(request):

    the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    form = DeliveryDateForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DeliveryDate(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            delivery_date = form.save(commit=False)
            delivery_date.cart = cart 
            delivery_date.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thank-you.html')

    return render(request, 'choose_delivery_date.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: Ah, thanks Tanguy. Your solution worked. It was my form validation that was incorrect.